# Django test - models.DoesNotExist: matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, testing

I have two test files, test1.py and test2.py. Individually they run fine, but when I try to run them using 'django manage.py test' I get the following error:

```
post.models.DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.
```

One more thing I notice is that, whichever file runs first will work well while the other throws this error (tested this by renaming files). I am using django.test.TestCase. This is the relevant code -

test1.py:

```
def setUpTestData(cls):
    Post.objects.create(...)
    Post.objects.get(id=1) #Works fine since this file runs first
```

test2.py:

```
def setUpTestData(cls):
    Post.objects.create(...)
    Post.objects.get(id=1) #Throws above error
```

I am new to testing in django so I think I'm missing something basic here.

Comment: I find it rather weird to use an `id` query in the first place. You have not the slightest guarantees that an `id` will start at `1`. This can depend on what is already stored in the database, the database system, etc.

Comment: Your test database table's sequence does not reset between tests. So the second time around the instance should have id `2`. If you expect it to only contain a single record, just use `get()` without params.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I thought the same, but doesn't database roll back after the test is run? I also tried calling Post.objects.all().delete() in tearDown method but it didn't work.

Comment: Hint: `Queryset.create(...)` actually returns the newly created object

Comment: @GarvitJain Sequences are usually unaffected by database transactions. So the rollback will delete the record, but the ids will nevertheless keep incrementing.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes I know there are workarounds, just wanted to know why this doesn't work

Comment: @schwobaseggl Ah I see. Thanks!

Comment: @GarvitJain actually using the return value of `Queryset.create()` is not a workaround but the proper way to get the newly created object when using auto primary keys.

Comment: @GarvitJain Actually, sequences have to be independent from transactions as concurrent transactions can create records in the same table.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I was actually using a for loop for creation and didn't want to insert 'if' blocks to get particular posts.